# Mapbox iOS SDK create a curve MGLPolyline with MKGeodesicPolyline get some strange

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapbox

I've tried to create a curve MGLPolyline on a map view using Mapbox SDK for iOS with following code,

```
func lineBetweenLocation(location1: CLLocation, location2: CLLocation)
{   
    var points: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]
    points = [location1.coordinate, location2.coordinate]
    let geodesic = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: &points, count:2)
    let line = MGLPolyline(coordinates: geodesic.coordinates, count: UInt(geodesic.coordinates.count))

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        // Unowned reference to self to prevent retain cycle
        [unowned self] in

        self.mapboxView!.add(line)
    })


}
```

With advantage of MKGeodesicPolyline, the code above works perfect only for a short distance!
If the given locations quit far like from USA to Asia, it will create an unwanted horizon strange line above the curve.

> There is no issue on Apple Map!

Please anyone help.
Thank you

[image]

[image]

Note: iOS 11.1 Xcode 9.1 Swift 4 , Mapbox-iOS-SDK Version 3.7.0

Comment: Could you clarify when and where you are calling `lineBetweenLocation(location1: CLLocation, location2: CLLocation)`?

Comment: On main thread with following points,

let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 37.785834, longitude: -122.406417)
        let destionationLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 8.11058700, longitude: 98.31253100)
        
        var points: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]
        points = [userLocation.coordinate, destionationLocation.coordinate] let geodesic = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: &points, count:2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact the the line cross the international date change line so it's wrapping all the way around.

To avoid that you can add or subtract 360 from your longitude to fix it. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js/issues/360

For example:

```
import Mapbox
import MapKit

public extension MGLPolyline {
    class func geodesicPolyline(fromCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, toCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> MGLPolyline {
        var coordinates = [fromCoordinate, toCoordinate]
        let geodesicPolyline = MKGeodesicPolyline(coordinates: &coordinates, count: 2)

        var normalizedCoordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
        var previousCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
        for coordinate in geodesicPolyline.coordinates {
            var normalizedCoordinate = coordinate
            if let previousCoordinate = previousCoordinate, abs(previousCoordinate.longitude - coordinate.longitude) > 180 {
                if (previousCoordinate.longitude > coordinate.longitude) {
                    normalizedCoordinate.longitude += 360
                } else {
                    normalizedCoordinate.longitude -= 360
                }
            }
            normalizedCoordinates.append(normalizedCoordinate)
            previousCoordinate = normalizedCoordinate
        }

        return MGLPolyline(coordinates: normalizedCoordinates, count: UInt(geodesicPolyline.pointCount))
    }
}

public extension MKPolyline {
    var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] {
        var coords = [CLLocationCoordinate2D](repeating: kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid, count: self.pointCount)
        self.getCoordinates(&coords, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.pointCount))
        return coords
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved my day! Ludovic Landry
Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have an alternative for Swift 4 ? geodesicPolyline.coordinates gives back an error saying that it does not have the property ".coordinates".

Comment: Updated the answer with a `MKPolyline` extension to provide `coordinates`

Comment: @LudovicLandry, Thank you.. I had found that extension on my intense search for answers, but I don't even know where I found it.. lol By any chance.. would you have an answer to this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918133/how-to-create-a-geodesic-polyline-with-ios-mapbox-sdk-curved-polyline-such-a